# Issue with codeigniter select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my codeigniter application try to retrive data from database. For that i use the following code

database.php:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "*****";
$db['default']['password'] = "****";

$db['default']['database'] = "mydbname";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In Model.php:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * from users";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    print_r($query);
```

but it return like

```
CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => [result_id] => [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => ) array(0) { }
```

empty result. How can i get the result from this.

Comment: $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result_array(); use this and check if the query is executing right or wrong?

Comment: try : print_r($query->result_array()); to get your resultset instead of the whole CI query object

Comment: @Vicky  still empty array

Comment: @JBA empty Array()

Comment: run query in `phpmyadmin`

Comment: @PathikVejani returns all the rows from the table

Comment: is that any problem with my database.php

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from users";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    print_r($query->result_array());
} else {
    $d = array();
    print_r($d);
}
?>
```

Comment: @Vini did you use `if` condintion?

Comment: @PathikVejani yes i used if. In localhost it is working well. In live server issue occur.

Comment: Check weather database library is loaded or not

Comment: @Vini set `'db_debug' => TRUE` and check

Comment: @PathikVejani if i set `db_debug' => TRUE` then this should happen `Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\jobblogger.no\domian\system\database\DB_driver.php`

Comment: @Vini good. then may be credentials are incorrect. double check them

Comment: @PathikVejani i tried second answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin

Comment: @PathikVejani the result would be `Connecting to database: developjobblogger
Connected OK:file: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain\application\config\database.php Line: 84`

Comment: no.. it won't work.. your project is on server not on localhost (in PC).. correct?

Comment: @PathikVejani yes it is in server

Comment: @Vini then there should be `localhost` in `hostname`

Comment: @PathikVejani i need to enter my IP address?

Comment: @Vini no.. check your username and password.

Comment: check 5th answer from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254049/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-your-database-server-using-the-provided-settin may be it works

Comment: @PathikVejani when using mysql_select_db it says database connected.

Comment: @Vini did you see 5th answer?

Comment: that is Lawrence answers is 5th for me

Comment: @Vini cehck this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632562/codeigniter-unable-to-connect-to-database-server-error

Comment: @PathikVejani  `You have specified an invalid database connection group.` when modify the active group

Comment: @Vini set it to default.. and use this `$this->load->database();` where you load the db

Comment: @PathikVejani return empty result

Comment: @Vini now i want credentials to check why not working

Comment: @PathikVejani i really appreciate your help. It is confidential one yaar.

Comment: @Vini ok no problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107863/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-vini).